# jquery dropdown select date picker and value from middle of list

Tags: jquery, append, html-select

I have made a jquery script which append's years as option to select menus.

How should it be configured so that default value is 2001 but when you click on arrow of select menu, you get larger years above 2001 and lower beyond it.

So that 2001 shows in the "middle" of list?

situation in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dzorz/mmeV7/

html:

```
<span class="label-f">seit:</span>
<select class="span2" id="seit" name="seit">
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
</select>
```

script

```
$(function(){
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
    {
        $('#seit').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove item you added through HTML and set selected option after combo is populated using `$('#seit').val('2001')`

**HTML**

```
<span class="label-f">seit:</span>
<select class="span2" id="seit" name="seit">
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 1900; i--)
    {
        $('#seit').append($('<option/>').val(i).html(i));
    }
    $('#seit').val('2001');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmeV7/6/)